# How can I tell which components are dead (water spill from son) Boots into windows after GPU swap

Tags: motherboard, gpu, desktop-computer, water-damage

I'm not sure what info is useful, so I'll give a top-level explanation, and then steps that I've taken.

My son was spinning in my chair after (foolishly) putting a small glass of water on my desk. He hit it, and it fell on my desk and dripped into my case. Upon visual inspection, there wasn't *much* water in my computer, and I was unaware of which components were affected.

Directly after being shut off and dried off (visually) - I tried to turn on my PC. only the RGB headers of my ram turned on. I asked a friend to come over to try the various components separately to isolate the failure(s). First we tried my GPU (GTX 1080Ti). His computer wouldn't boot with it in. That led us to believe that it was the GPU that was done for. After removing this seemingly-dry GPU, the movement seemed to release a tiny bit of residual moisture onto my hand. Not a good sign.

Removed a spare RX580 from another computer, and rechecked my components. All looks good. My computers posts with my GPU, and the CPU/RAM/HDD all show working correctly.

Windows boots, and (obviously) my resolution is super low. After a minute of it installing drivers, I get my 1440 resolution, but my computer stops responding. Not good.

I restart my computer, and it's the same thing. I can boot perfectly fine into windows, and it will run perfectly for about 1-2min, then it just COMPLETELY stops responding. The start menu no longer shows up, and the only response I can get is right clicking on the task bar. Reset and repeat. What troubleshooting steps would you recommend I take to isolate any potentially failed components? I don't have spares, and I can't afford to just 'dartboard' it. Is it even possible for a water-damaged CPU/Mobo/etc to continue to function for a small amount of time before going dead? It's also hard to believe it's a heat issue because I can *immediately* restart it with the same results (1-2min of working). Here are my specs:

- Ryzen 3800x CPU with Wraith Prism cooler
- GIGABYTE AORUS ELITE Wi-fi Rev 1.x Motherboard
- Corsair Vengeance RGB Pro RAM (2x16GB) 3600mhz
- (formerly) GTX 1080Ti (assumed dead)
- (currently) ATI Sapphire Pulse RX580 GPU
- Samsung 980 M2 SSD (working and passed BIOS testing)
- Cooler Master 850w PSU (seemingly working - all voltages are within spec)
- Windows 10 64bit Pro (latest version)

If I've left anything out, please let me know, and please help me fix this computer. I work on it! :/

Comment: Take it to a repair shop for proper cleaning & diagnosis. You started well; switch off & dry visually… then it all went wrong. You powered it up before getting it cleaned properly. At minimum you should have stripped it & sprayed it down with contact cleaner, then left it for a couple of days. You have component shorts & potentially corrosion to find now, on things you need a magnifying glass to see.

Comment: Swapping an nvidia card for an AMD one should work, but meh, i wouldnt trust it. Make a live linux cd (on usb stick) and boot into that, see if it lasts longer than 2 minutes.  If that runs fine, it might only take reinstalling windows.

Comment: I didn't have the time. I had a work thing I *needed* to try to get. It's also weird that it would work perfectly for 2min and then go to hell. If there's a short, then there's a short. It wouldn't just *magically* appear/disappear at the time same. At least to my experience. Even if there *is* a short, wouldn't it just be the mobo at that point, correct? I should mention that the amount of water found in the PC was minimal (at least to my eye).

Comment: You're arguing from a false perspective; that because there's not much water, there can't be much damage; then working on the hope of 'well, I got away with it so far'. Neither of these explains 'after a water-spill, I get intermittent behaviour' & neither will find the fault, because it is in all probability too small to see with the naked eye. You allowed your initial water spill to go uncorrected, & re-applied power. Now, days later, you have not only the initial shorting, but also corrosion.

Comment: So I was able to determine that the failure is entirely GPU. I had to restart windows and clear the display drivers, but my RX580 works flawlessly (albeit really poorly next to the 1080Ti). However, here's where things take a turn. I cleaned off the GPU to the best of my ability, not really having the money to just take it to a repair center, and I *did* briefly get power. However - a resistor/capacitor/SMC literally caught fire before I could pull the plug. Is there any way to repair that? It seems pretty isolated to just one component. Any chance?

Comment: If you have to ask, the answer is probably no, I'm afraid. You'd need your own hot air rework station for starters, you can't do modern PCBs with a soldering iron. You'd also need to be confident enough to identify & source the required components & be able to test whether the visible fails were the only fails. Your equipment investment costs would be more than a new card.